Cross tenant access in oracle cloud infrastructure
Use case:
I have 2 oci accounts / tenancies tenantA (home region US) and tenantB (home region India). In tenantA, I have a compartment called compA. I have created a storage bucket inside compA called bucketA. I want to manage this bucket from tenantB.
I have followed this document to do the same: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/database-tools/doc/cross-tenancy-policies.html
What I have done:
Created a group in the default domain called groupB
Created the following policy in tenantB root:
Define tenancy tenancyA as ocid1.tenancy.oc1..
Endorse group groupB to manage object-family in tenancy tenancyA

Created the following policy in tenantA root:
Define tenancy tenancyB as ocid1.tenancy.oc1..
Define group groupB as ocid1.group.oc1..
Admit group groupB of tenancy tenancyB to manage object-family in compartment compA

Now, I have authenticated the oci cli using the tenantB credentials and running the following command:
oci os bucket list --compartment-id 'ocid1.compartment.oc1..' --config-file /Users/user/.oci/config --profile tenancyB --auth security_token

Expectations:
Bucket list containing bucketA
Actual
404 error
You do not have authorization to perform this request, or the requested resource could not be found
Help needed
Unable to debug the issue, can someone help to achieve the cross tenancy access?
